Can nginx be made to process `add_before_body` *BEFORE* the main request is processed?
The nginx directive add_before_body allows processing another request whose response is then prepended to the primary request body. The order of request processing is as follows:

Main request is processed (passed to upstream, etc).
The add_before_body request is processed and prepended (or appended in the case of add_after_body).

For my particular purpose, I need the add_before_body request to be made before the main request is processed. Is this possible?
Clever tricks with proxies, etc. are welcomed.
